# Internal Server Error 500 Shopware 5.2

Tags: .htaccess, plugins, shopware

after upgrading Shopware 5.1 to 5.2.12, I get the Error Message every time I open the Plugin Manager:

"500 Internal Server Error Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log. Was hat dieser Fehler zu bedeuten? Dieser Fehler kann viele verschiedene Ursachen haben. Die h�ufigsten Fehler sind: bei PHP das Script hat zu viel CPU-Ressourcen verbraucht und wurde beendet das Script hat zu viel Memory-Ressourcen verbraucht und wurde beendet. In diesem Fall finden Sie eine Zeile �hnlich wie diese in Ihrem error.log "Unable to allocate X bytes" .htaccess Datei mit falschen Befehlen (mehr Informationen im error.log) weitere Informationen finden Sie in der Datei error.log im Ordner logs bei Perl und anderen Scriptsprachen das Script hat zu viel CPU-Ressourcen verbraucht und wurde beendet das Script hat zu viel Memory-Ressourcen verbraucht und wurde beendet. In diesem Fall finden Sie eine Zeile �hnlich wie diese in Ihrem error.log "Unable to allocate X bytes" Script wurde nicht im ASCII Modus hochgeladen Script hat falsche Rechte (korrekt: 755) der Pfad zum Interpreter in der 1. Zeile ist nicht korrekt .htaccess Datei mit falschen Befehlen (mehr Informationen im error.log) weitere Informationen finden Sie in der Datei error.log im Ordner logs"

It is now not possible anymore to update any Plugins or to see any installed Plugins. Therefore it is not possible to go on productive mode unless the plugins are not updated. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you what to do? "Please contact the server administrator, ..."

Comment: ... that's at the moment me :D

Comment: Well, then you certainly know how to tackle internal errors. You certainly _did_ take a look into your http servers error log file. Since that is what is explained in the documentation which you certainly _did_ read.

Comment: Yes, i did. Nothing else than: _End of script output before headers: php5.6_ is in the error log...

Comment: Ah, great! If so, then why didn't you post that valuable information in your question? ;-) That is a very vague error... but I would dare a "long shot" here: file permissions. Depending on _how_ you upgraded it might be that your http server is not able to access certain files any more and files to even initialize the engine.

Comment: Allright. Than its my mistake - Sorry. Any ideas how I can do any checks which permission it might be?

Comment: Well, you are the administrator... So you should have access to the system... How exactly is a question of what base system you work on. Assuming that you use a Linux system as most people do for such task you probably will use the `ls` command. That _should_ be familiar to you...

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe I got your question wrong. Maybe you ask what file permissions you actually need... Well, I'd say your http server needs read access to the php files. So find out which system account the http server is operated under (probably something like www-data, again assuming you are using a normal Linux system). So that accout or needs read access. Or you use group file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if this shop is not a productive instance, [enable PHP's display_error](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/debugging/#default-log-output) in your `config.php` and then you should see, what went wrong.

Also, check your error_log for permission denied or something. E. g. on my UNIX system after clearing the cache on console, the permission rights were reset sometimes. Check this, too. So, check the rights on the following folders:

```
var
web
files
media
engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community
```

For a first try give it all the rights `0755`. If errors appear again, make it world-writeable, so `0777`.

Try also to clear the cache on console using

```
cd ./bin
php console sw:cache:clear
```

Maybe you will see there faster an error, if any.